# svn anonimous access

Tags: svn, linux

Как настроить линуксовый svnserve для выдачи некоторых данных анонимным пользователям?

В `svnserve.conf` стояло `anon-access = none` и анонимные пользователи не могли ничего получить. Поставил `anon-access = read`, после этого стало невозможно скачать данные, используя логин и пароль, сервер выдавал: "Not authorized to open root of edit operation".

Как настроить анонимный доступ и не потерять доступ по паролю?

Answer (score 2):

**svnserve.conf**

```
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
```

**authz**

```
[/]
$anonymous = r
$authenticated = rw
```

И все это есть хорошо расписанное в документации SVN: [глава Server Configuration, раздел Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html)